# Count subarray elements and sum deep subarray elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, sum

I'm working with an API that returns a JSON object which I then decode into an array using

I need to get a count of all the `[data]` items in the array, and then generate a total of all the `[Total]` values contained in each

Here's my array:-

```
Array
(
    [errorCode] => 0
    [result] => OK
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fieldData] => Array
                        (
                            [Due Date] => 11/30/2017
                            [Date] => 11/30/2017
                            [Total] => 128.97
                            [Customers::Company] => A B C Lock & Key
                            [Status] => Paid
                            [Date Payment] => 11/30/2017
                        )

                    [portalData] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [recordId] => 1
                    [modId] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fieldData] => Array
                        (
                            [Due Date] => 12/01/2017
                            [Date] => 12/01/2017
                            [Total] => 256
                            [Customers::Company] => Kim Peacock Beringhause
                            [Status] => Paid
                            [Date Payment] => 12/01/2017
                        )

                    [portalData] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [recordId] => 2
                    [modId] => 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fieldData] => Array
                        (
                            [Due Date] => 11/30/2017
                            [Date] => 11/30/2017
                            [Total] => 1880
                            [Customers::Company] => Norton, Robert L Esq
                            [Status] => Unpaid Overdue
                            [Date Payment] => 
                        )

                    [portalData] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [recordId] => 3
                    [modId] => 0
                )

            

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [fieldData] => Array
                        (
                            [Due Date] => 12/22/2017
                            [Date] => 12/22/2017
                            [Total] => 1278
                            [Customers::Company] => Shapiro, Mark R Esq
                            [Status] => Unpaid
                            [Date Payment] => 
                        )

                    [portalData] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [recordId] => 10
                    [modId] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I've tried:

```
count($array)
```

which returns `3` which I can see are the count of the 3 items in that parent array (errorCode, result and data), but I can't work out how to focus on the `data` only.

The count value I'm after is `4` and the total value is `3542.97`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For count you need to do:

```
count($array['data']);
```

And for getting sum of all `Total` index values:

```
echo array_sum(
         array_column(
             array_column(
                 $array['data'],
                 'fieldData'
             ),
             'Total'
         )
     );
```

***Reference:-*** [PHP: array_column - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)